# jQuery code proceeds in an unexpected manner

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

For some reason the code is behaving strangely.
This happens in the If Else function. In the Else part, its supposed to fadeOut over 1000ms and then remove the Class and then go onto the next statement. But apparently the second statement gets called out first and it makes everything go bad . :( .

```
$(function() {

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if((e.target.id == 'RWorld') || (e.target.id == 'abc'))
    { 
    $(".sborder").fadeOut(1000, function() {

    $(".sborder").removeClass("sborder");
    });
    }

});




$("div#inner").children().click(function() {


//$("div#inner .sborder").removeClass("sborder");

var name = $(this).attr('id');

//alert($("div#inner").find("div").hasClass("sborder"));
if($(".sub"+name).hasClass("sborder"))
{
    $(".sub"+name).fadeOut(300, function() {
    $(".sub"+name).removeClass("sborder");
    });
}
else
{



    $(".sborder").fadeOut(1000, function() { 
    $(".sborder").removeClass("sborder");});       // The Problem is in here. This piece of Code doesnt work exactly as i thought it would ...

    $(".sub"+name).addClass("sborder").fadeIn(1000);

}
});
});
```

Please help :(.

Comment: You should really use delegates instead of implementing them manually... `$(document).on('click', '#RWorld, #abc', function() { ... })`

Comment: Using consistent code indentation can really work wonders for code comprehensibility. In this case, you probably wouldn't have wasted time trying to track this bug down (probably wouldn't have had the bug at all) if you used any of the standard forms of indentation. Just FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the fadeIn to happen at the same time as the fadeout, correct? In that case you need to cache your query results like this:

```
var $sborder = $(".sborder");
$sborder.fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $sborder.removeClass("sborder");
});
$(".sub" + name).addClass("sborder").fadeIn(1000);
```

Your problem was the removeClass("sborder") was removing the sborder class you added to $(".sub" + name) because it was happening 1 second later. In other words the order things were happening was as follows:

1. Start fading out what currently has a class of "sborder"
2. Add class of "sborder" to $(".sub" + name)
3. Start fading in $(".sub" + name)
4. 1 second after item 1. started fading out remove the class of "sborder" from every element that **now** has a class of "sborder" which now includes every element returned by $(".sub" + name) because of item 2.

On a best practices note, when using jQuery...

- Whenever possible, try to always **drill down from something with an id or tagname** ( $('#container .sborder') ). Searching by class **can be** very slow in older browsers and adding some context means that jQuery doesn't have to search through your entire document.
- Whenever possible, try to **cache your query results**. Every time you call $('.something') it is querying the DOM. So if you cache the results in a variable only one query needs to be made.  Obviously only do this if you know the DOM hasn't changed in the interim. In our case here, we know the DOM has changed but we only want to affect the elements that had "sborder" a second ago.

Comment: Thank You so much. Could you please explain what this Caching thingy is ?

Comment: The reason jQuery is called jQuery is because its querying your document for objects. It just uses CSS-like syntax to do so. When you call $() and pass it a selector string like '.sborder' it goes looking for elements and returns results. If you place those results in variable like $sborder jQuery doesn't have to run the query again it can just use what it already found. So caching your results can be used to be more efficient or in our case to remember the way things were. BTW, the $ in $sborder is just a way to remember that its a jQuery result set and that you have jQuery methods available.

Comment: Awesome Explanation. If you could just spare some time to tell me why didnt it follow the order. I would be so grateful. :)

Comment: because animations are performed asyncronously. Meaning that the code after your animation method gets called happens as soon as the the animation starts, not after it finishes. That's why you're passing a function to fadeOut in the first place. You're saying "When the animation is finished, do some stuff". At that point you were requerying your doc and finding more elements with a class of sborder, because the line after fadeOut had already happened.

Comment: also @thecodeparadox is correct.  My code is not exactly correct because I'm assuming you want '.sborder' to only find one element. Here is a fiddle with the hybrid approach that will get your fadeOut and fadeIn to happen simultaneously and for multiple items if you ever need that. http://jsfiddle.net/bczengel/nYjnU/

Comment: OMG. You are so AWESOME.!!!!!!!~ You made it CRYSTAL CLEAR . AWESOME AWESOME AWESOME. How do i give this guy. +1000 ratings xDDDD. Thank You so much bczengel :). You helped me learn a bit more ^^!~

Comment: Here is the Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/neoragex/xLAPL/4/ . On Click each Div gets a Sublayer but at the same time it checks if the others has them. If they do, its supposed to fadeOut and then remove   the class and finally add a Class with the fadeIn effect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11485/discussion-between-bczengel-and-learningslowly)

Comment: *"Searching by class is very slow..."* What gives you that impression? It might have been true in IE7 and earlier, but all modern browsers (in standards mode) support `querySelectorAll` and provide very fast handling of common use-cases (like searching by class name). Out of curiousity, I just loaded up the single-page version of the HTML5 spec (a truly massive document) and asked Chrome to search for a non-existant class. Took 11ms. 'course, that's Chrome. Took Firefox 15ms. Don't happen to have IE handy. I'd expect it to be a bit slower, but...

Comment: You're correct that modern browsers use the querySelectorAll method but until IE7 and 8 are gone ( and I can't wait ), why not make the few adjustments that require little effort and can make the parts of your audience that may still be on older browsers not have a bad experience. Not all of us have the luxury of shunning the older browsers. That being said I will modified my answer above slightly.

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

```
$(".sborder").fadeOut(1000, function() { 
$(".sborder").removeClass("sborder");});
$(".sub"+name).addClass("sborder").fadeIn(1000);
```

With correct indention:

```
$(".sborder").fadeOut(1000, function() { 
    $(".sborder").removeClass("sborder");
});
$(".sub"+name).addClass("sborder").fadeIn(1000);
```

What you probably want:

```
$(".sborder").fadeOut(1000, function() { 
    $(".sborder").removeClass("sborder");
    $(".sub"+name).addClass("sborder").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".sborder").fadeOut(1000, function() { 
    $(this).removeClass("sborder"); // $(this) is enough to refer to current $('.sborder')
    $(".sub"+name).addClass("sborder").fadeIn(1000);
});
```